# C Anagram Function

Tags: c

I have an anagram function that is not working the intended way I want it to.

**For Example** these correctly work such that the function returns 1:

- `is_anagram("a bc", "Cab")`
- `is_anagram("a12+-", "1a2")`

But the function **incorrectly** returns 1 for:

- `is_anagram("1a3", "1a +=")`

The code is:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int is_anagram(char *s1, char *s2) {
    // 2 Empty Num Arrays
    int s1_count[99] = {0};
    int s2_count[99] = {0};
    int c = 0;    
    while (s1[c] != '\0') 
    {
        if (isupper(s1[c])) 
        {
            s1_count[tolower(s1[c]) - 'a']++;
        }
        else 
        {
            s1_count[s1[c] - 'a']++;
        }
        c++;
    }
    c = 0;
    while (s2[c] != '\0') 
    {
        if (isupper(s2[c])) 
        {
            s2_count[tolower(s2[c]) - 'a']++;
        }
        else 
        {
            s2_count[s2[c] - 'a']++;
        }
        c++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    {
        if (s1_count[i] != s2_count[i]) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", is_anagram("a bc", "Cab")); // expected to print 1
    printf("%d\n", is_anagram("a12+-", "1a2")); // expected to print 1
    printf("%d\n", is_anagram("1a3", "1a +=")); // expected to print 0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read this: [ask] and then [edit] the question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried to debug it yourself? Run your program in a debugger and step thru the code to trace the flow and variable values to find out where things first start going wrong.

Comment: I guess `tolower(s2[c]) - 'a'` doesn't make much sense with anything else than letters (a-b, A-Z).

Comment: Ask yourself: what are `s1_count` and `s2_count` used for and how does that help finding an anagram?

Comment: BTW what is `MAX_STR_LEN`? Depending on what it is, you might have an additional problem. Show a [mcve].

Comment: So when you're handling the space (ASCII code 32) `s1_count[s2[c] - 'a']` amounts to `s1_count[32-97]++` (ASCII code for 'a' is 97). Negative subscript??

Comment: I reverted the latest edit, since it did not reproduce the original problem anymore. You wrote that the function returns 1 for all the three examples, but the latest code did return 0 in those cases. Note that S.O. is not an interactive support forum. You shouldn't continuously update your question with the latest version and wait for further help. You should ask a question that focuses on **one** specific problem, and that question should get answered. Please read [ask]. Also, next time, please post a [mre]. I helped you with making a MRE this time so it's easier for others to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want s1 and s2 to contain non-letter characters (as in your examples), then you need to change a few things:

1. You shouldn't subtract 'a' from your index because for characters like numbers for example, that would give you a negative index.
2. Your final loop shouldn't be from 0 to 25 only (which implies the 26 letters). You should iterate through all possible characters, i.e. through the entire s1_count/s2_count arrays.
3. The size of your s1_count and s2_count arrays should be enough to accomodate all possible valid characters, so either 128 if you want the basic ASCII set or 256 if you want the entire set.

BTW, you don't need the check for isupper(). You can just call tolower() on every character. If it's not an uppercase letter, it will return the character unmodified.

Comment: Hi @pdp8, I've taken your suggestions into my code. I've changed s1_count and s2_count to sizes of 128, and for the final loop to iterate through the count arrays correctly and no longer subtract from 'a' however still not getting it to work properly!